# Is it possible to put multiple methods in a single .m file separated from the main classdef file?

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a class with many methods. I know i can story separate functions in the @Class folder. As some functions are related I was wondering if it is possible to store multiple functions in a single methods file.
The reason is that i want things stay clear and structured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: you can either store your class in a single file, or you can use an `@` folder. If you use an `@` folder, you can store methods either in the main class file, or in a single separate file for each method. You can have several methods in the main class file, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Only the first function in an M-file is visible from outside the M-file. Other functions are private.

Note that there is no difference between a regular function and a class method in the `@Class` folder, except that MATLAB dispatches calls to functions in `@Class` folders only if one of the input arguments is of that class.

Relevant parts of the MATLAB documentation:

- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html
- https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/how-to-use-methods.html

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is creating a function that calls one of the other functions inside the file by creating a handler based on one of the inputs. Yet this is more like building a giant switchcase inside a file to adress different functions and might lead to many error potentials:

```
function X=multifun(varargin)   
   if (nargin==0)
      X='first of many error potentials';
      return
   end
   functionhandle=str2func(varargin{1});
   X=functionhandle(varargin(2:end));   
end

function x=a(varargin)
    x=sum([varargin{1}{:}]);
end

function x=b(varargin)
    x=mean([varargin{1}{:}]);
end
```

So by passing the name of the wanted function as a string you can adress it as a private function through the main function of the file.

```
multifun('a',2,3)

ans =

     5

multifun('b',2,3)

ans =

    2.5000
```

Yet again you can see what has to happen with the input arguments (`[varargin{1}{:}]`) which is just terrible practice. So

theoretical possible - yes.

recommendable - no.

Comment: Tx for the idea. I accept your recommendations as it becomes a bit ugly and wont help keep things simple.
The reason a was looking for a solutions is that im building a program that is used by others but a couple of methods im only using by myself so I dont want to distribute them. But keeping them in a single file helps me keeps the overview.